# Verilog- Why is my state machine output arriving one clock cycle earlier?

Tags: fpga, verilog, counter, delay, state-machines

I'm writing a Verilog code for a state machine with 4 states. state 0 is buffer time of 1 microsecond. state 1 is trig pulse for 10 microseconds. in state 2, the input is read. If the input is high for 588200 ns, the output should be high until reset is pressed.

Instead of using delay, I've used counters and timers (20ns becomes 1 clock cycle). But I'm getting the output pulse high one clock cycle earlier than expected. Here's is my code-

```
always @ (posedge clk_50M) begin
if(!reset) timer <= timer +1'b1;
else timer<=0; 
if(timer>50550) timer <=0;
end

//state transitions and conditions
always @(posedge clk_50M)  begin 
case (state) 
s0: begin
     if(timer > 50) begin //1us
        state<=s1;
        end 
     else state <=s0;
     end
s1: begin 
     if (timer > 550) begin //10us
        state<=s2;
     end 
     else state<=s1;
     end
s2: begin
     if (timer >= 50550) begin //here read input
       state<=s3;
     end
     else state<=s2;
     end
s3: begin 
        state<=s0;
     end 
default: state<=s0;
endcase 
end
//what happens in the changed states
always @(posedge clk_50M) begin
if(reset) begin 
trig <=0; 
output <=0; 
pulses <=0; 
end
else begin 
case (state) 
s0: begin 
        trig<= 0;
     end
s1: begin
        trig<=1;
     end
s2: begin
        trig<=0;
        if(input) begin 
            pulses<=pulses+1'b1;
        end
     end
s3: begin 
        if(pulses == 29410 && !reset) begin
        output<=1;
        end 
     end
endcase
```

[image]

This is the waveform of its simulation. The first waveform is the actual output, the second is the expected output and the third is the net error.
Can someone help with this problem?

Comment: First of all I can see a problem that you may want to resolve prior to identifying the other timing issue.  Generally speaking only <= (non-blocking) assignments should be used in an always@(posedge Clock) block. You are not meant to use = (blocking) assignments in always@(posedge Clock) blocks. One is supposed to use always@(posedge Clock) blocks when you want to infer an element or more, that changes its value at the positive or negative edge of a clock. You're code actually only uses one non-blocking assignment on the fourth line : if(timer>50550) timer <=0;

Comment: Once you resolve this issue you should then debug the rest so that you get the correct result.

Comment: PS also the graph is not showing properly. Please correct the question to fix it.

Comment: I've done the changes in the question now

Answer (score 1):

Check this code carefully:

> ```
> s2: begin
>     if (timer >= 50550) begin //here read input
>        state<=s3;
>     end
>     else state<=s2;
>     end
> ```

I see a few potential issues:

- This waits for 50,000 clock cycles after the previous state transition. That comes to 1,000,000 ns (1 ms), not the 588,200 ns you said you wanted to remain in this state.
- Your problem description says you want to read an input when in this state and only count time while that input is high. There is no dependence on any input (aside from the clock) in the code, so you will simply wait 1 ms, ignoring any input signals.

  To add a dependence on an input signal, you'll probably want to modify the counter incrementing code to use an increment enable signal, and generate the increment enable signal as an output of the state machine.
- If you want to increase the wait time by 1 cycle you can simply change the test condition from `timer >= 50550` to `timer > 50550`. This also keeps the test condition consistent with what you used in the other states, making the code easier to follow for future readers.

Comment: I'll have to change the timer reset condition too, right?

Comment: @Milli_Wizard369, yes I think your timer reset is giving you one extra cycle also.